# How to perform letter-spacing on text in a QComboBox?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5, pyside2

The QWidget stylesheet allows to perform `spacing` and not `letter-spacing` between characters. In the Combobox I am setting up in a GUI has more or less readable text for its `currentText` but with a terrible letter spacing for the font [**MS Shell Dlg 2,8**]. Changing the minimum size of the box doesn't change readability. Changing the **'spacing : 1'** by setting its stylesheet moves the text a little to the left of the cbo and does not improve readability.

Is there an option to perform "letter-spacing" so letters are just a few pixels more apart from each other?

Combobox details are: all settings default. The geometry:

```
width  = 110
height = 22
```

Test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel, QHBoxLayout,
                             QComboBox, QApplication)

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()

        self.lbl = QLabel('Ubuntu', self)

        combo = QComboBox(self)
        combo.setFixedSize(100, 22)

        combo.addItem('Species', userData='100')  # text readable here but not when construcuted.
        combo.addItem('Xubuntu', userData=200)
        combo.addItem('Gentoo' , userData=300)

        combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)

        hbox.addWidget(combo)
        hbox.setSpacing(20)

        hbox.addWidget(self.lbl)
 #       self.setContentsMargins(20, 20, 20, 20)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.move(300, 300)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 180)
        self.setWindowTitle('QComboBox')
        self.show()

    def onActivated(self, text):

        self.lbl.setText(text)
        self.lbl.adjustSize()
        
        print(self.sender().currentText())
        print(self.sender().currentData())
        sys.stdout.flush()

def main():
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The original combobox code can be found here http://zetcode.com/pyqt/qcombobox/.

Answer (score 1):

In fact there is. The changes are not made in the QComboBox stylesheet but rather in the font section (Qt.Gui.QFont). So below code show how to change it. Keep in mind that when box dimensions are fixed and the text is larger than its max dimension it will result in not showing the complete text; rather you have to scroll to the right in the combobox.

Don't forget to 'set' the new value at last otherwise the new values are not used.

```
font = combo.font()                 # getting font metrics 
value1 = font.letterSpacing()       # getting line spacing value 
        
font.setLetterSpacing(QFont.PercentageSpacing, 200)
        
value2 = font.letterSpacing()
        
combo.setFont(font)                 # sets the font for the object
        
print(f'old {value1} | new : {value2}')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Consider that using fixed sizes is usually not suggested, especially for widgets that are text-based: even if you're *absolutely* sure that the user will use the font you're choosing, there might be some issues in case the DPI is different than what you're using on *your* screen. In any case, remember that QComboBox has the [`sizeAdjustPolicy()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#sizeAdjustPolicy-prop) property which allows more control on how the combo is resized based on its contents.